# Change playback of flash object via html or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, flash, actionscript

is it possible to change the playback speed of a flash object without having to recompile the flash object, i.e through the html attributes or javascript?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can call a function within your SWF file from JavaScript ([ExternalInterface. addCallback](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29)) that changes your animation's FPS... However, you would need to create the function in your flash file and recompile it once.

You could also create a loader SWF that has this functionality, and load your old flash movie from it.

Comment: Any additional information you can provide on developing the loader SWF you mention? I asked the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028697/loader-swf-with-variable-playback-controls-possible Thanks in advance.